# ExitThread versus Allowing Thread Function to Exit Normally - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2008

My application has a thread that is created using `CreateThread`.  What is the difference between calling `ExitThread` from within said thread and allowing the thread to exit normally (i.e. reaching the end of the thread function)?  I am using C++ and Visual Studio 2008.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, something very important:

**..., in C++ code, the thread is exited before any destructors can be called or any other automatic cleanup can be performed. Therefore, in C++ code, you should return from your thread function**

(Edit [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682659(VS.85).aspx))

Comment: +1, straight from the API docs on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682659(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Also it is important to note that, from the docs: `ExitThread is the preferred method of exiting a thread in C code.`

Comment: @Justin Ethier: Are you sure that ExitThread is the preferred method? From the docs: "For an executable file linked with LIBCMT.LIB, do not call the Win32 ExitThread API; this prevents the run-time system from reclaiming allocated resources. _endthread and _endthreadex reclaim allocated thread resources and then call ExitThread."

Comment: Agree, from same source: `A thread in an executable that is linked to the static C run-time library (CRT) should use ... _endthread ... rather than ... ExitThread.`

Comment: @Eric - That is what the first sentence of the docs states... looks like it is misleading to take that at face value.